# Is a FreeBSD equivalent of pppd required? If yes, is it /usr/sbin/ppp?

Tags: freebsd, tunnel, ppp, pppd

On [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Protocol_daemon) and [the official webpage](http://ppp.samba.org/), only Linux and Solaris are listed as possible platforms. The [FreeBSD handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/ppp-and-slip.html) mentions pppd, but it is used to refer to the kernel implementation in section [28.2.1.2](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/userppp.html#AEN34140). Since it was removed in 8.x, I suppose it is better to do ppp from userland.

Is a daemon not required? Should I use `/usr/sbin/ppp` as a replacement? Is it always available?

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be mpd http://mpd.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

From the [ppp(8) manual](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ppp&sektion=8):

> This is a user process PPP software package.  Sometimes, PPP is implemented as a part of the kernel (e.g., as managed by pppd) and it is thus
>        somewhat hard to debug and/or modify its behaviour.  However, in this
>        implementation PPP is done as a user process with the help of the tunnel
>        device driver (tun).

It is part of the base system, so it is available by default. (Unless you've re-built the system from source and have specified in `/etc/src.conf` that you don't want ppp built.)